# Bound on product of sinc functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, upper-lower-bounds

I know that $\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}$ can be bounded as follows

$$-\alpha \leq \frac{\sin(ax)}{ax} \leq 1$$

where $\alpha \approx \frac{2}{3\pi}$.

I am facing trouble trying to extend this to a product of sinc functions

$$\prod_{i=1}^d\frac{\sin(ax_i)}{ax_i}$$

How to derive a bound tighter than

$$-\alpha \leq \prod_{i=1}^d\frac{\sin(ax_i)}{ax_i} \leq 1$$

Comment: Shouldn't the lower bound be at least as good as $\alpha^d$?

Comment: You can get $-\alpha$ with $\sin(a x_1)/(a x_1) = -\alpha$ and all other $x_i \to 0$.